# Массив незапланировано становится пустым

Tags: ios, swift

Ума не приложу, что происходит с массивом outputArray.. Почему, когда я его уже заполнил, он снова становится пустым, когда завершается выполнение функции API_WRAPPER.request( withPhotoId... )

```
import Foundation

class ACPhotoManager
{
    class func recivePhotoList( withSuccess succes : (JsonResponse : JSON) -> Void, failureBlock : ( errorCode : Int) -> Void ) -> [ACPostItem]
    {
        var outputArray = [ACPostItem]()
        API_WRAPPER.request(Const.RequestConsts.countOfElementsOnPage, withSuccess: { (JsonResponse) in
            //print(JsonResponse)
            let photoArray = JsonResponse["photos"]["photo"].arrayValue
            for var photo : JSON in photoArray {
                let photoId = photo["id"].stringValue
                let photoTitle = photo["title"].stringValue
                API_WRAPPER.request(withPhotoId: photoId, withSuccess: { (JsonResponse) in
                    let urlArray = JsonResponse["sizes"]["size"].arrayValue
                    for var url : JSON in urlArray {
                        if (url["label"].stringValue == "Medium 800") {
                            let dataSource = url["source"].stringValue
                            let localPhoto = ACPostItem( photoWithId: photoId, photoWithTitle : photoTitle, photoWithURL: dataSource )
                            outputArray.append(localPhoto)
                        }
                        // ЗДЕСЬ МАССИВ ЗАПОЛНЕН ДАННЫМИ !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                        print(outputArray)
                    }
                }, failureBlock: { (errorCode) in
                    //Const.Fails.noConnection()
                })
            }
            // ЗДЕСЬ МАССИВ СТАНОВИТСЯ ПУСТЫМ !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            print(outputArray)
        }) { (errorCode) in 
        }
        return outputArray
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Правильно сказать, что он еще не заполнен, когда Вы распечатываете содержимое этого массива. Выполнение происходит асинхронно и когда Вы распечатали его здесь:

```
ЕСЬ МАССИВ СТАНОВИТСЯ ПУСТЫМ !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        print(outputArray)
    }) { (errorCode) in
```

То `API_WRAPPER.request(withPhotoId:` только начал выполняться.