# Как изменить переменную

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

Добрый день! Помогите новичку изменть переменную `users` `LoginViewController'a`.
Вот код ниже
Вне метода `UserService` переменная юезра, которая изменятся в блоке равна пустому массиву, в то время, как внутри блока все рабоатет и она равна массиву юзеров.

Не могу понять в чем дело

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    var users = [User]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        UserService.getUsers() { users in
            self.users = users
            print(self.users) // Здесь выводятся юзеры
            print("1: \(self)") // Здесь LoginViewController
        }
        print(self.users) // Здесь выводится пустой массив
        print("2: \(self)") // Здесь LoginViewController
    }
}
```

P.S. заранее спасибо за терпение и помощь!

Comment: Попробую угадать, UserService.getUsers() это некий запрос? (session.dataTaskWithURL к примеру), тогда проблема в том, что работа происходит на разных threads.

Comment: ответ уже дали на каком то другом ресурсе. проблема оказалась в том, что UserService.getUsers() выполняется асинхронно. Я так понимаю, что print2 выполняется перед print1, чего автор вопроса не указал.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Массив незапланировано становится пустым](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/530688/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%bc)